# Issues in splitting logic

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

Hi I have below string and I have to split and put in a map . While splitting through string tokenizer or .split method i am not getting the result i want.Below is my string

```
{"errorCode":"specialChars.allowed","errorParams":["a-zA-Z0-9^][_{|}=~!\"#$%&()*+,-.:'\\/?@space"]}
```

I want

```
 Key:errorCode Value:specialChars.allowed 
Key:errorParams Value:[
  "a-zA-Z0-9^][_{|}=~!\"#$%&()*+,-.:'\\/?@space"
]
```

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer by clicking on the tick mark if you feel my answer is the solution of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since your input String is a JSON String, you can use Gson API to convert it into a Map.

```
String str = “{‘errorCode’:’specialChars.allowed’,’errorParams’,’[“a-zA-Z0-9^][_{|}=~!\"#$%&()*+,-.:'\\/?@space”]’}”;
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, String> myMap = new Gson().fromJson(str,type);
```